# How to convert a date to Quarter

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to convert a date to `Year-Quarter` format. Below is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as datetime

pd.PeriodIndex(datetime.date(2020, 6, 15), freq='Q-MAR').strftime('Q%q')
```

Which this I am getting below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/period.py", line 241, in __new__
    data = period_array(data=data, freq=freq)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/period.py", line 892, in period_array
    data = list(data)
TypeError: 'datetime.date' object is not iterable
```

Can you please help how to correct this error? I expect to get result as `2020-Q2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If working with scalar need [`Period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/pandas.Period.html):

```
print (pd.Period(datetime.date(2020, 6, 15), freq='Q-MAR').strftime('Q%q'))
Q1


print (pd.Period(datetime.date(2020, 6, 15), freq='Q-MAR').strftime('%Y-Q%q'))
2020-Q1


print (pd.Period(datetime.date(2020, 6, 15), freq='Q').strftime('%Y-Q%q'))
2020-Q2
```

Or add `[]` for one element list:

```
print (pd.PeriodIndex([datetime.date(2020, 6, 15)], freq='Q-MAR').strftime('Q%q'))
Index(['Q1'], dtype='object')
```